# Characteristic Function and Quantile Function?

Tags: probability, distributions, quantiles, characteristic-function

Characteristic functions (cf) are closely related to cdfs and pdfs of random variables, for example

- cf is the Fourier transform of the pdf
- [Inversion formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) from Lévy and Gil-Pelaez

Question: **Is there any link (integral representation) between a cf and the inverse cdf (or quantile function)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of a cdf $F : \mathbf{R} \mapsto [0,1]$ is usually
$$
F^{-1}(p) = \inf\{ x : F(x) \ge p \}.
$$

The way you invert a c.f. $\phi$ to get measures of intervals is
$$
\mu([a,b]) 
= 
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it} \phi(t) dt.
$$

So you can put these together:
$$
F^{-1}(p)= \inf\{ x : \lim_{a \to -\infty}\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itx}}{it} \phi(t) dt \ge p \}.
$$
Does this satisfy your needs?